# Trying to Get Parent ComboBox from MenuItem in the ComboBox's Items

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, menuitem

I have a `ComboBox` whose `ItemsSource` I've set to an `ObservableCollection<object>` in code.  I also have two `Button`s that, when clicked, adds either a `ComboBoxItem` or a `MenuItem` with three sub `MenuItem`s of its own to the `ObservableCollection`.  When I click on one of the sub `MenuItem`s, I want to be able to get the parent `ComboBox` housing all of this, so that I can set its `SelectedItem` as the parent `MenuItem` (the one with the sub items).

I've tried various methods, but have had no success.  Here's what I'm currently working with:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DynamicComboBoxTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid Name="mainGrid">
    <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,17,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" IsEditable="True"/>
    <Button x:Name="comboButton" Content="combo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="132,44,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="comboButton_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="menuButton" Content="menu" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="132,71,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="menuButton_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

C#:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace DynamicComboBoxTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ObservableCollection<object> comboBoxSource = new ObservableCollection<object>();
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            comboBox1.ItemsSource = comboBoxSource;
        }

        private void MenuItem_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            (sender as MenuItem).IsSubmenuOpen = true;
        }

        private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //I want to get the parent 'ComboBox', in this case, the one named "comboBox1" from the 'MenuItem' that triggered this event.
            var a = (sender as MenuItem).Parent;
            var b = (a as MenuItem).Parent; //<-----this, I thought, would be the 'ComboBox' I'm trying to get, but it's null :C
        }

        private void comboButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBoxItem comboBoxItem = new ComboBoxItem();
            comboBoxItem.Content = i.ToString();
            comboBoxSource.Add(comboBoxItem);
            i++;
        }

        private void menuButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem();
            menuItem.Header = i.ToString();
            menuItem.GotFocus += MenuItem_GotFocus;

            MenuItem subMenuItem1 = new MenuItem();
            subMenuItem1.Header = j.ToString();
            subMenuItem1.Click += MenuItem_Click;
            MenuItem subMenuItem2 = new MenuItem();
            subMenuItem2.Header = (j+1).ToString();
            subMenuItem2.Click += MenuItem_Click;
            MenuItem subMenuItem3 = new MenuItem();
            subMenuItem3.Header = (j+2).ToString();
            subMenuItem3.Click += MenuItem_Click;

            menuItem.Items.Add(subMenuItem1);
            menuItem.Items.Add(subMenuItem2);
            menuItem.Items.Add(subMenuItem3);

            comboBoxSource.Add(menuItem);

            i++;
            j += 3;
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, I can get the parent `MenuItem` of the sub `MenuItem` just fine, but I cannot get the `ComboBox` that houses the parent `MenuItem`.  When I try to get it in this bit:

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //I want to get the parent 'ComboBox', in this case, the one named "comboBox1" from the sub 'MenuItem' that triggered this event.
    var a = (sender as MenuItem).Parent; //yay parent 'MenuItem'!
    var b = (a as MenuItem).Parent; //<-----this, I thought, would be the 'ComboBox' I'm trying to get, but it's null :C
}
```

`b` (the `LogicalParent` of the parent `MenuItem`, `a`), which I had hoped would be the `ComboBox` I'm after, is null.

One of the things that's confusing me is that if I add the `ComboBox`es/`MenuItem`s directly to `comboBox1`'s `Item`s like so:

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(menuItem); //assume 'menuItem' has sub 'MenuItem's
```

Everything works fine, and I'm able to follow the various `LogicalParent`s until I get the `ComboBox` I'm looking for.  Same is true if I add the `MenuItem`s in the XAML.

This is all from a test solution I'm trying to get working.  In the final project, I am not able to get direct access to the `ComboBox` as I could here by simply referencing it (`comboBox1`).  The final project will also have several hundred `ComboBox`es each with x number of `MenuItem`s, and I'd rather not have to set a variable or something for each of those `MenuItem`s referencing its parent `ComboBox`.  It is for these reasons (and I'm sure others I'm forgetting...) that I would just like to walk back up the tree and get the parent `ComboBox` from the clicked sub `MenuItem`.

The reason I'm setting the `ComboBox`'s `ItemsSource` to an `ObservableCollection` rather than just using `comboBox1.Items.Add()` is because I'd ideally like to populate all of my various `ComboBox`es at once rather than iterating through each `ComboBox` and adding hundreds/thousands of items to them one at a time, especially since they'll all be populated with the same set of `ComboBoxItem`s/`MenuItem`s.

Hopefully I've explained this well enough.  I've been wracking my brain over this for the past few days, so it's pretty fried at the moment >_<.  Apologies if I've left out any details or something doesn't make sense.  This is my first foray into WPF, so simple yet detailed explanations would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks in advance! :D

PS: Please ignore the fact that the `Submenu`s never close.  That'll come later :P.  Also, any ideas why the sub `MenuItem`s are white? (I suspect it either has to do with the `ItemsSource` vs. `Items.Add()` nonsense or the `GotFocus` event)

Comment: You usually should not have collections of UI elements unless you author a custom control.

Comment: Which collection are you talking about?  The ObservableCollection, or do you just mean the hundreds of ComboBoxes I referred to?  In the final project, I DO have a custom control that inherits from ComboBox (it's basically just a ComboBox that stores extra data/has extra functions) that stores the ComboBoxItems/MenuItems.  Each of those custom ComboBoxes is housed by another custom control that have one custom ComboBox each along with various other elements.  I'm just trying to get the basics working in ^this^ example.  Out of curiosity, why is it bad to have a collection of UI elements?

Comment: It's about model/view separation, commonly in WPF there is very little view code ("code behind" of windows and user controls), yet people sometimes have lists of UI elements in their model or view-model, where UI elements do not belong.